# Track first time leveling up

Tags: architecture, rpg

Broad question, but I'm looking for some better ideas.

Currently I have a Player class and booleans for hasSeenLevel2, hasSeenLevel3, etc. When I give a player exp I call a checkLevel method that checks to see if they level up.

```
checkLevel(){
    if(totalExp > 100){
         level = 2;
         if(!hasSeenLevel2){
             display("You gained level 2");
             hasSeenLevel2 = true;
         }
    }

}
```

this works, but is incredibly tedious to setup and inefficient.

What better ways are there to organize player levels and exp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have multiple variables with names which just differ by a number, you should really consider if an array is more appropriate. So you should first replace your `hasSeenLevel2`, `hasSeenLevel3`, etc. variables with an array `hasSeenLevel` with one entry per level.

You should also use an array for storing the exp values required on each level to reach the next.

```
const int LEVEL_CAP = 5;
bool hasSeenLevel[LEVEL_CAP + 1];
int expForNextLevel[LEVEL_CAP];

expForNextLevel[1] = 100;
expForNextLevel[2] = 300;
expForNextLevel[3] = 500;
expForNextLevel[4] = 1000;    

checkLevel(){
    while(totalExp >= expForNextLevel[level]){
         level++;
         if(hasSeenLevel[level]){
             display("You gained level" + level);
             hasSeenLevel[level] = true;
         }
    }
}
```

When your exp table isn't handmade but follows a fixed formula, you can alternatively populate the `expForNextLevel` array procedurally at startup.

Note: In the `expForNextLevel`array, the 0th index is not used and in the `hasSeenLevel` array, the indexes 0 and 1 are unused. You could fix that by subtracting 1 and 2 from the level whenever you access these array, but that's a large cost in code readability for a minuscule decrease of memory consumption, so I would really recommend you to live with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code way of doing it.

```
expForLevel = [100, 200, 300, 400]

currentLevel = 0
maxLevelReached = 0
currentExp = 0

checkLevel
  if currentExp >= expForLevel[currentLevel]
    currentLevel += 1
    if currentLevel == maxLevelReached + 1
      print "cool for your new level bro: level " . currentLevel
      maxLevelReached += 1
    else
      print "cool, you reached that level again: level " . currentLevel
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do this depending on the architecture of your engine and how your players are designed.

## Method 1: Array

As Phillip described, when storing variables whose names differ by incremental values, it's best to use a container of those (implied) variables. With an array, you simply assign the value (flag in this case) by the index. That being said, for this use case (level flags), you'll be setting a hard upper limit on levels; and, you would be breaking encapsulation.

## Method 2: Associative Array (Dictionary)

Depending on the language you're using this may or may not be better than an array. Unlike the array, this can extend as levels are added; however, an error catch must be implemented to catch  error types.

## Method 3: Event Management System

I would recommend implementing an EMS system as you'd avoid having to store a variable to check against. With an EMS system, you'd simply fire an event when the Person levels up. That event in turn calls back a function which prints the intended message. Ideally the event would carry a variable containing the level they just hit, which is then in the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

For determining the amounts per level, use an array as others have pointed out.

For the message logic, you need but one extra piece of state: `unlocked_level`. When the player earns enough XP, print your message and bump `unlocked_level`. When the player actually levels up, bump only `level`. The invariant is that `level <= unlocked_level`.

```
levels[] = {0, 100, 250, 700, 2000, ..., sentinel}

gain_xp(int amount):
  self.xp += amount
  while self.xp >= levels[self.unlocked_level]:
    self.unlocked_level += 1
    print 'You are now level ', self.unlocked_level

can_level_up():
  return self.xp >= levels[self.level]

level_up():
  if can_level_up():
    do_level_up_stuff
```